# Unable to get lowest value using join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `info` and `sell_info`. `info` table contains "list of record" and `sell_info` contains "product which are on sale".

I want to get "lowest" value of record where `id = 1`. How can i do this?

Here is my table "info":

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | XYZ |
| 3 | CDE |
| ... | ... |

Here is my table "sell_info":

| id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Expected result is (getting lowest price of id="1"):

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 3 |

Comment: How are tables `info` and `sell_info` related ?
From your expected output; 
It Looks like  `info.id = sell_info.product_id`

Comment: @Tushar you are right , primary key is "info.id" and foreign key is "sell_info.product_id"

Answer (score 0):

The following query would give you what you want.

It uses an inner query to get the minimum price for each product ID from the `SELL_INFO` table. It then uses the product ID from that inner query to join to the `INFO` table, to get the name of the product.

```
SELECT
  INFO.ID, 
  INFO.NAME,
  MINP.MIN_PRICE
FROM
  INFO as INFO
  INNER JOIN 
  (
  SELECT 
    SI.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT_ID, 
    min(SI.PRICE) as MIN_PRICE
  FROM
    SELL_INFO as SI
  GROUP BY
    SI.PRODUCT_ID
  ) as MINP
    ON INFO.ID = MINP.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE
MINP.PRODUCT_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.name, MIN(s.price) as price
FROM info as i, sell_info as s
WHERE i.id = s.product_id AND i.id = 1
GROUP BY i.id, i.name
```

Comment: I too did the same here my [result](https://dbfiddle.uk/TI81QcjR)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy.
Here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3ce7f/1).

```
select i.id, i.name, s.price
from info i
JOIN sell_info s ON i.id = s.product_id
WHERE i.id = 1 AND s.price = (
    SELECT MIN(price)
    FROM sell_info
    WHERE product_id = 1
);
```